# Unauthorized in getting request : MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

For validation in my code, I'm using the passport.js. When I'm using get request method I'm getting error as

> Failed to load http://localhost:3000/users/profile: Request header
>   field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

This is my code.

```
    authToken: any;
        getProfile() {
            let headers = new Headers();
            this.loadToken();
            headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
            headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
            return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile',{headers: headers})
              .map(res => res.json());
          }
        loadToken(){
           const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
           this.authToken = token;
         }
storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }
```

This is from my routes file

```
// Profile
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({user: req.user});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having trouble with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS): a mechanism that gives webservers cross-domain access controls, which enable secure cross-domain data transfers.

Easiest fix, [`npm i cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)
and then in your Express.js app, before anything else:

```
const cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Or if you don't want an additional dependency:

```
var app = express();
app.use( (req,res,next) => {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
   next();
})
```

Comment: yes I'm using cors & also   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
  });

Comment: Hmmm strange. I see no reason why it wouldn't work that way. Are you sure you're calling this piece of code before your routes ? 
`express.use( <CORS Shenanigans> ).use('/routes",router)`

Comment: Yes I'm using them before routes